# Many gettimeofday in Apache 2.4 + fcgid + centos 6.6 - Long Wait time for static files

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, redhat, apache-2.4

When i perform a strace on apache process, i see many gettimeofday before & after GET request, even when Apache returns a static file like an image file. It results in a long downtime period before Apache 2.4 (with php 5.6, fcgid) answers the GET request.

```
 1616       0.000048 read(156, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n", 8000) = 16
1616       0.000099 gettimeofday({1430592206, 931114}, NULL) = 0
1616       0.000044 gettimeofday({1430592206, 931156}, NULL) = 0
1616       0.000035 read(156, 0x7f01d4007018, 8000) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
1616       0.000042 poll([{fd=156, events=POLLIN}], 1, 7915439 
1670       0.020724 <... epoll_wait resumed> {}, 100, 100) = 0
1670       0.000039 gettimeofday({1430592206, 951998}, NULL) = 0
1670       0.000037 gettimeofday({1430592206, 952034}, NULL) = 0
1670       0.000033 gettimeofday({1430592206, 952066}, NULL) = 0
1670       0.000032 epoll_wait(155, {}, 100, 100) = 0
1670       0.100265 gettimeofday({1430592207, 52366}, NULL) = 0
1670       0.000041 gettimeofday({1430592207, 52405}, NULL) = 0
1670       0.000033 gettimeofday({1430592207, 52437}, NULL) = 0
1670       0.000033 epoll_wait(155, {}, 100, 100) = 0
1670       0.100324 gettimeofday({1430592207, 152804}, NULL) = 0
1670       0.000066 gettimeofday({1430592207, 152865}, NULL) = 0
1670       0.000073 gettimeofday({1430592207, 152941}, NULL) = 0
1670       0.000060 epoll_wait(155, {}, 100, 100) = 0
1670       0.100251 gettimeofday({1430592207, 253247}, NULL) = 0
1670       0.000039 gettimeofday({1430592207, 253284}, NULL) = 0
1670       0.000032 gettimeofday({1430592207, 253316}, NULL) = 0
1670       0.000032 epoll_wait(155, {}, 100, 100) = 0
1670       0.100241 gettimeofday({1430592207, 353597}, NULL) = 0
1670       0.000061 gettimeofday({1430592207, 353653}, NULL) = 0
1670       0.000071 gettimeofday({1430592207, 353727}, NULL) = 0
1670       0.000045 epoll_wait(155, {}, 100, 100) = 0
```

There are a lot of them before the server actually returns the response to GET.

What i have done:

- I have setup ExtendedStatus off in httpd.conf just in case.
- I have followed the advice of red Hat team by doing a

  ```
  echo "kernel.vsyscall64 = 2" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
  ```

  & editing sysctl afterwards.
- echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/vsyscall64

That slightly increased the reponse speed of Apache 2.4 but it is still slow and there is a lot of Gettimeofday. I have no modsecurity and only standard modules of Apache. Nevertheless, i suspect a module.

I have checked whether it was ioncube 5.0.2 but it wasn't.

Is it normal?
If no, do you think it could come from a module from Apache?

edit: it looks like it matches with 3 timestamps copied to 3 logs, writing down three errors/warnings.

thank y.

Comment: The strace looks a little weird. How are you testing it? I see the GET request being incomplete. There should be two newlines at the end of request, before server starts sending any response. You can see that there is one read, which ends in one newline, then another read on the same FD, which returns EAGAIN (no data in yet) and then there is different thread (notice the pid in first column) waiting on different FD (which may by just the listen socket). `gettimeofday` as you see them, should be pretty harmless. Your problem is someplace else.